# RewriteRule in .htaccess based on language variable

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rss

I've a website which contains german as default language and english as alternative language. I want to redirect my rss url to another path in the website based on language condition.

I mean 
 http://www.eample.com/rss.xml to http://www.eample.com/index.php?type=11 in default case and
http://www.eample.com/en/rss.xml to http://www.eample.com/index.php?type=11&L=1 in the case of alternative language.

I've tried this in the following way, but it only respect the default case.

```
RewriteRule rss.xml$ /index.php?type=11 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule en/rss.xml$ /index.php?type=11&L=1 [L,R=301]
```

Can you guys please help me to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
RewriteRule ^rss\.xml$ /index.php?type=11 [NC,L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^en/rss\.xml$ /index.php?type=11&L=1 [NC,L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe throw in some regex to capture additional country/language codes.

```
RewriteRule ^rss\.xml$ /index.php?type=11 [NC,L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(en|de|fr)/rss\.xml$ /index.php?type=11&L=$1 [NC,L,R=301]
```

or match any two characters

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/rss\.xml$ /index.php?type=11&L=$1 [NC,L,R=301]
```